# Camera light while capturing image with python

Tags: python, camera

I want to Capture a simple picture from my laptop camera. I wrote a simple program with `pygame` and it works fine, but my problem is when I try to capture the picture the led light of camera turn on and never turn off until my Python code reaches the end. It is annoying because the user never knows when it taking pictures.
Here is my sample code:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
import time
import sys
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(camlist[0],(640,480))
cam.start()
time.sleep(0.1) 
img = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(img,"out.jpg")
cam.stop()
print("camera stopped!")
time.sleep(10) #the light is still on
```

Comment: Can't promise this will work, but try `del cam` after you've stopped the camera. Potentially it's keeping the light on while the object exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @kindall, I've needed to delete the object:

```
class My_Camera:
    def __init__(self,camshot_file):
        self.other=others()
        self.camshot_file=self.other.resource_path(camshot_file)
        pygame.init()
        pygame.camera.init()
        self.camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()

    def grab(self):
        try:
            self.cam = pygame.camera.Camera(self.camlist[0],(640,480))
            self.cam.start()
            sleep(0.1)
            img = self.cam.get_image()
            pygame.image.save(img,self.camshot_file)
            self.cam.stop()
            return True
        except:
            return False
    def stop(self):
        del self.cam
```